# Harley Davidson: Can the engine be damaged by too much oil?

Tags: motorcycle, oil-change, harley-davidson

The question is particularly concerned with a
Harley Davidson Dyna Street Bob Special 2016(103  ci).

Before winter season I did all recommended tips to store my bike during the winter, oil change was one of them. It was my first oil change with a Harley and my instruction-book(manual) told me to fill 2.8 Liters in it after running the engine for "some time" and draining all oil.

I ran the engine for approximately 2 mins. After that I let the oil drain for 10 - 15 mins until no more drop came out of the engine anymore. Until now I expected that most of the oil is out and didn't check the oil level again while filling the engine up. After filling (exact) 2.8 Liters in it, I started the engine for 2 mins. After that I checked the oil level again and was shocked that the oil level exceeded by far the hot-max-level. I therefore let some oil drain until the oil level reached the middle-level between cold(low) and hot(full). It occurred a month ago and since that I can not calm myself down.

My question is: What consequence does this oil-overfill have in terms of engine-damage?

Thank you very much for your expertise.

Comment: I cannot comment directly as I don't have any experience with HD's, but realistically you probably did absolutely no damage to the engine. I understand being concerned about a new bike, but really, if it doesn't run any different without any noises after the fact, you shouldn't be overly concerned. Leaving this as a comment because I don't know *for sure*. Hopefully someone with regular HD experience will be able to answer for you.

Comment: One should only check the oil level when the vehicle is cold, and standing on level ground.   Running the motor splashes oil everywhere, and makes the dipstick read high.  Then you wipe the dipstick, repeat the reading, and the oil level reads low, which is confusing.   "cold+level, wipe first, and then read the dipstick" is the normal process.

Comment: @Criggie : Thank you very much, I'm going to do it. Unfortunately I already read the dipstick after cleaning it. While the engine is still cold, it should be between low and high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already driven my bike for a week, **it turned out that this oil-overfill had no effect on anything**. At the beginning my bike rocked a little bit more (it's a dyna), but after I drove 2-3 kilometer approximately, the tour was smooth as if you were riding on a cloud. Until today there have been neither strange noises nor oil-leaks at all.

What I learnt is that when changing oil:

1. **Drive at least 5 - 10 minutes** so that most of the oil is in the tank below the engine and it's likely that you get rid of all old-oil while draining it (during the night for instance).
2. Always check the oil-level while filling little quantities in because according to my manual I had to fill in 2.8 Liters, but this might be too much especially when there are still great quantities somewhere around and not in the tank itself. **So do not fill the instructed quantities of oil in all at once, but one step at the time (0.5 Liters) while checking the oil-level**.
3. Before you first ride check the oil-level otherwise your bike might spill it out somewhere (air-filter for instance) that can cause crashes as well.